# memory usage of grails application

Tags: grails, memory-management, out-of-memory

I want to know about how much memory can a grails application use.
Does it depend on the number of domain classes, plugins installed?
I am develpoing an application and when I test it on tomcat it continuously goes out of memory.
currently using almost 500MB.

Moreover if this is not the case, can you suggest me what methods of memory management can be used?

Comment: btw, does 'out of memory' means that your tomcat crashes at some point of time?

Comment: No it doesn't crash. I get the logs continuously. Well I will check the code first and resources being used. then confirm it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [Grails Java Melody](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody) plugin.  It will give you all kinds of statistics on your running app, in your case the memory stats should help but there is so much more to this Swiss Army knife of app monitoring.

Initially have you tried playing with JVM settings eg: -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -Xms256m -Xmx512m

Answer (score 2):

Java, and Groovy, and Grails have very high level of minimal usage of memory. 500Mb is really small amount, and it's pretty common to start from 1Gb (I mean tomcat memory configuration). So, don't worry about 500Mb, it's ok.

As about domains, classes, etc - of course all new classes, all new code, it requires some memory, but i'm sure that for your case it's just a few percents of memory, all other is used by Grails libraries, Tomcat, JVM, etc.

PS there is also common Tomcat problem with `PermGem space` - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=permgem+space

Comment: how do we increase the permgem space? I mean to ask in which file of tomcat

Comment: If you have permgem space issue - just restart Tomcat on every deploy. You can increase it by using `-XX:MaxPermSize=500m' but it's only delays the problem

Comment: So how is this sorted completely? Yeah at each deploy I restart and problem is gone. but it runs out of memory after few hours . Right now its working fine for more than 20 hours

Comment: Hm, if run's out of memory, when you didn't make deploy, then it's possible error in your code (at least if you're not trying to limit it to 500m, because it's really not enough for Java). You can see used resources by using VisualVM