# Optimising memory consumption for Grails applications deployed on Raspberry Pi

Tags: grails, tomcat7, raspberry-pi

I have developed an application using Grails 2.1.1 and I am trying to deploy it on a Raspberry Pi (latest mode B with 512MB RAM) with java 1.8.0-ea + Tomcat7. But when I start the tomcat server, it takes about 30mins to deploy the application and then the response time of the server is very long. I checked the memory and there is around 10MB left, but I guess my application actually consume more RAM than that.

The free memory when the pi bootup is about 387MB. I have tried to deploy a clean app with nothing in it but whatever generated by the default "grails create-app myapp", and the free memory drop to 107MB. Because I need Spring-security-core and Spring-security-ui plugins, so I also tried a clean app with those plugins. In this case, the free memory drops to 88MB.

So is there any way (optimising the code or deployment) to manage the memory consumption of a grails app to around 200MB as I also need to deploy some other things on the same Pi? I also used Hibernate, searchable-plugin and quartz in the application. Or should I give up as it's not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend running any *non-"Hello World"* style Grails application on Raspberry Pi.

**In general**, 512MB of RAM would be a minimum, in order to have a decent performance on a medium to smaller application.

Tomcat memory usage + your app memory usage on 512MB of RAM doesn't look good on Raspberry Pi to me...

See the second answer from Igor [on this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184906/memory-usage-of-grails-application).

Please consider other alternatives Spring MVC or something more lightweight(Not too many proxies, low amount of reflection in the Web Framework, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I have been tuning the memory and tomcat for a these days and find out that there is actually no way to dramatically reduce the memory consumption. However, I didn't expect a lot of people using the application at the same time. So I finally manage to use Jetty as standalone server, and removed many unnecessary packages in the deployed war/jar file. The performance of starting the server and response time for gsp page become acceptable.