# What is the minimum memory footprint for a simple grails application?

Tags: grails, heroku, grails-2.0

We are deploying a simple REST grails (2.3.7) app to heroku. The application is doing little less than "Hello World", yet we exceed the 1x dyno limit of 512MB (usually going between 600-700MB).

What is the expectation of memory usage of such an application?

Also, is there an official minimum requirements concerning memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently the minimum for a basic application is around or just above the 512mb amount depending on what the app does. We are aware of the problems this creates for Heroku and currently you need double dynos to run Grails applications on Heroku.

We are working to improve Grails support for micro services and a smaller memory footprint in Grails 3.0.

Comment: Can you provide us a updated answer? Since I'm using Grails 3.2.5 I would like your advise about how many memory to use. @Graeme Rocher

Answer (score 1):

See this question stackoverflow : 
[memory usage of grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184906/memory-usage-of-grails-application)

and what i can say is based on

> If memory is not a problem on your server then allocate a large amount of memory, such as 512M or more. Also use the server VM option. EG: (-server -Xms512M -Xmx512M). Usually it is better to set both min and max heap size to the same in server applications.
>   However, if you running on a virtual host with limited memory, Grails 1.0 RC1 has been tested on tomcat 6 with both -Xmx96M and -Xmx128M, it performed well with both settings. I've heard reports of it running on lesser configurations"

And , REST application memory requirement can be high according to the request and how complex query and results involved, And also how you managed to do the coding that you properly cleared out every session , object after use ? But , i guess for REST application one `> 512 <= 1GB` of memory is good to start. And , use so tweaks for memory as well. it should be fine!